# how to know line number from the offset in java

Tags: java, text

I tried to search for my problem  on the net but I could not find a solution. I have a text file and I know an offset, I would like to know the line number in the file that has that offset. I would like to have a code snippet in Java. 
thank you

Comment: Have you tried [LineNumberReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/LineNumberReader.html), is is not what you needed?

Comment: Please define "offset"

Comment: Yes I have tried LineNumberReader, but seam that id does not do the job. Offset refers to the position of a character in the string for example , the position of character number 68, I would like to know in which line this position.

Comment: @Rabe Does the "offset" include the newlines, or just the text? E.g. line 1 is `Hello` and line 2 is `World`. On windows that's stored as `Hello\r\nWorld\r\n`, a total of 14 "characters". --- Is offset 1 the `H` or the `e`? Assuming 0-based, so `e`, is offset 7 then the `r` or the `W`?

Comment: @Rabe And in case your text is not in a single-byte character set, is the offset in bytes or characters?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shown any code in your question so we can't help resolve the actual problem that you have. You say that LineNumberReader doesn't do that job, but it does; if you had shown your code, we could have pointed out where the problem is.

Below is a simple implementation. You'll need to do some work to turn this into a re-usable function in your program.

```
int offset = 12345;
try (LineNumberReader r = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader("myfile.txt"))) {
    int count = 0;
    while (r.read() != -1 && count < offset) {
        count++;
    }
    if (count == offset) {
        System.out.println(r.getLineNumber());
    } else {
        System.out.println("File is not long enough");
    }
}
```